# Keep focus on menu when mouse go onto submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I search to keep focus on my first menu when the mouseenter go onto my submenu.

http://jsfiddle.net/6rXJ5/32/

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#galerie-menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
            var $elem = $(this);
            var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
            $sub_menu.stop(true)


                 .animate({'top':'188px'},1000,'easeOutBack')
                 .show()
                 .andSelf()
                 ;                         

        }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
            var $elem = $(this);
            var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');

                $sub_menu.hide().css('top','0px');
                });
    });
</script>
```

you can find my jsfiddle to see my menu.

help :)

Comment: I can't see submenu in your fiddle, are you sure it's working?

Comment: Clean and simplify your example

Comment: To see submenu, you have to select jQuery UI 1.8.5 on the left sidebar

and I will try to simplify it

Comment: It's updated with many block on css delete

Comment: erf i loose the link ^^'

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6rXJ5/31/    the new link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6rXJ5/33/

Answer (score 0):

keep trying with

$('#galerie-menu > li').addClass('classname');

give some style properties to class

Comment: I'm a beginner with jquery or javascript so.. :x i will check addClass